# SUM () ,CROSS JOIN Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cross-join, mssql-jdbc

I've MYSQL Query with SUM & CROSS JOIN, its working fine.

MYSQL QUERY:

```
SELECT SUM(totexec/(pass_count+fail_count))/d.total  COUNT FROM test_schedule CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM test_schedule WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) d WHERE project='JupiterQA'
```

But I'm trying to execute this same query in MSSQL in showing "Column 'd.total' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

After that I added GROUP BY a.total in end of the query,
ERROR IS:
Divide by zero error encountered.

I've records in all the table,Is Query wrong?

Comment: must `a.total ` `d.total` in group by?

Comment: I"ve only alias d, so that am using d.total. but a.total?

Comment: Is in your question "GROUP BY a.total".

Comment: Oh sorry that one is d.total only

Answer (score 0):

i'm not askin why you use a cross join :D
just add a group by clause in your query

```
SELECT SUM(totexec(pass_count+fail_count))d.total  COUNT FROM test_schedule CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM test_schedule WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) d WHERE project='JupiterQA' GROUP BY d.total
```

Comment: I added GROUP BY d.total after that only I got error.I mentioned above question itself.

Comment: okay, why are you using slashes ? mssql may interpret this to divide by d.total

Comment: am doing divide operation,without slashes how can do the divide operation?

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent to the MYSQL query:

```
SELECT tSum / dTotal AS COUNT
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(totexec / (pass_count+fail_count)) AS tSum, d.total AS dTotal 
   FROM test_schedule 
   CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) total 
                FROM test_schedule 
                WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) d 
   WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) t
```

I don't see a need for a `CROSS JOIN` though. This should also do the job:

```
SELECT tSum / ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM test_schedule 
                WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) AS COUNT
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(totexec / (pass_count+fail_count)) AS tSum 
   FROM test_schedule 
   WHERE project='JupiterQA' ) t
```

Comment: its throwing divide by zero error, but I have data's

Comment: @user3114967 Either `pass_count+fail_count` or `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM test_schedule WHERE project='JupiterQA'` is zero.

Comment: @user3114967 Do a select on `pass_count+fail_count` and `SELECT COUNT(*) total ...` first to see what values you get.

Comment: sum (pass_count+fail_count) value is: 1432  SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM test_schedule  WHERE project='JupiterQA' value is :1257

Comment: @user3114967 What do you get if you execute: `SELECT SUM(totexec / (pass_count+fail_count))  FROM test_schedule WHERE project  = 'JupiterQA'`?

Comment: @user3114967 Did you finally managed to tackle division by zero error? I am just curious as there is no obvious reason for this error to occur.